# How can this file be treated as a directory?

Tags: php, forms, file, http, directory

I was just bouncing around glassdoor and my dev panel was open. I saw this on the [contact page](http://resources.glassdoor.com/contact-sales-side.html)

```
 <form class="lpeRegForm formNotEmpty" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://resources.glassdoor.com/index.php/leadCapture/save" id="mktForm_1059" name="mktForm_1059">
```

What is this `action="http://resources.glassdoor.com/index.php/leadCapture/save"`? How does a file followed by a slash work? Where does it instruct the computer to go?

Comment: That's what we call `URL Redirect`! See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection Or it's just `index.php which is called!

Comment: It's most likely a mod rewrite setup in `.htaccess` probably to trump bots in thinking it's a 404 in order to drive them nuts and get them to `not` come back and submit the form if it isn't human or a spammer. Sneaky but effective. Bravo to the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a script name is followed by more path components, the webserver runs the script, and the remaining components are put in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. So when `index.php` reads `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` it will get `"/leadCapture/save"`.